# Binding property based on enum

Tags: wpf, data-binding

My WCF applicaiton supports downloading books from a remote service.
The user sends a request to the service to download a book, the service gets the request and donwloads the book. in response, it sends the download progress based on enum value to the client.

my view :
https://onedrive.live.com/redir?resid=3A8F69A0FB413FA4!123&authkey=!AJK3wiB_C_LqayQ&v=3&ithint=photo%2cpng

The status is enum value.

```
public enum Status { Pending, Started, Completed };
```

BookModel

```
public class BookModel
    {
        public string Title { get; set; }
        public string Author { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }
        public Status Status { get; set; }
    }
```

My task is to update the ui based on the enum value.

pending - should display 0% filled pie.

stated - should display 50% filled pie.

completed - should display 100% filled pie.

The required property that should be updated is "EndAngle" (double data type) of PieSlice object (inside Book.xaml).
I bound this property to "Percent" object in my BookViewModel, however when the book status is changing, the pie is not get updated with the new status value.

thanks.

Book.xaml

```
  <Label Grid.Row="0">Title</Label>
        <Label Grid.Row="1">Author</Label>
        <Label Grid.Row="2">Description</Label>

        <TextBlock Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding Title}"/>
        <TextBlock Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding Author}"/>
        <TextBlock Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding Description}"/>
        <Button Grid.Column="2" Grid.RowSpan="3" Command="{Binding SaveCommand}" Content="Download" />


        <Ellipse   Grid.Column="3" 
                    Height="20" Width="20"  
                    Stroke="Black" 
                    StrokeThickness="0.5" 
                    HorizontalAlignment="Center" 
                   Grid.Row="1"
                    />
        <Controls:PieSlice Grid.Column="3" Grid.Row="1" Stroke="Black" Fill="Black" 
                             Height="20" Width="20" 
                             StartAngle="0" EndAngle="{Binding Percent}"
                             HorizontalAlignment="Center" />
```

BookViewModel

```
  public class BookViewModel : ViewModelBase
    {
        private readonly BookModel Book;

        /// <summary>
        /// Initializes a new instance of the MainViewModel class.
        /// </summary>
        public BookViewModel(BookModel model)
        {
            this.Book = model;
        }


        public double Percent
        {
            get
            {
                return Book.Status == Status.Pending ? 0 :
                    Book.Status == Status.Started ? 180 :
                    Book.Status == Status.Completed ? 360 : 0;
            }
        }
     public Status Status
        {
            get
            {
                return Book.Status;
            }
            set
            {
                Book.Status = value;
                RaisePropertyChanged("Status");
            }
        }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> By calling RaisePropertyChanged("Percent") in the setter of Staus the
>   view will query Percent and hence retrieve the correct value.

View is bounded to Percent, a calculated property. when Status is updated, the Percent (property updates) but view bound to Percent will not update. This is because the view does not know that Percent has changed (we never told it). Percent also does not have a backing property!

```
 public Status Status
    {
        get
        {
            return Book.Status;
        }
        set
        {
            Book.Status = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged("Status");
            RaisePropertyChanged("Percent");
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You are not raising any PropertyChanged for `Percent` property.
You can put `RaisePropertyChanged("Percent");` just after `RaisePropertyChanged("Status");` so when you change the `Status` value `Percent` notify get raised too.